# Cannot connect to Database MySQL from workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I am try to using MySQL Workbench but its showing error "Cannot connect to database".Neither it taking it localhost or my Endpoint of AWS RDS as DNS in host in workbench.
"I am using Xampp for mysql server running on port number 3306 "

Error :
Cannot connect to DataBase Server

Your connection attemp to failed for user 'root' from host to server at localhost:NULL;
can't open named pipe to host:pipe:MySQL (2)

Please:
1.Check that mysql is running on server localhost.
2.Check that mysql is running on port NULL (note 3306 is the default,but this can be changed)

3.Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address  .
4.Make sure you are both providing a password if nedded and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you are connecting from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the connection to MySql, Use [Heidi](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) (i recommend it). If it didn"t work, check if your DataBase server is running in port 3306 by taping:

> netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen".

You can also change listenning port in /xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini:

> **my.ini:**
>
> ---
>
> Password = your_password 
>     port             =  3306  --->  3307
>     socket           =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"``

---

Comment: I tried to change password but it didn't work for it .By the way how to use this command .Is it in root directory ??

Comment: To use this commande go to commande line and type it. this commande list all openning port in your server. If you didn't see the 3306 port appear on it, this means your server isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no port configured. Check your connection settings that you have a port set.

[image]

Comment: I m using as3306 which is my port address and same configuration u said but ...when I am writing \r in MySQL directory ,it's says error not able to connect.

Comment: But the error message says port is NULL (localhost:NULL) which seems to indicate you haven't really set a port in the connection. Did you set the connection method to Standard (TCPI/IP)? The mentioning of named pipes could indicate you have this set to a named pipe (which only works on localhost and only on Windows and doesn't need a port, but  a pipe name).

Comment: YES,i am using TCP/IP and localhost but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.By the way in connection method i also tried to use endpoint of my RDS instance but still again there noot working.